# Trying to delete rows in a spreadsheet based on the date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to loop through the rows of my sheet to delete certain rows based on the date found in column F. I have an syntax error showing up on line 28. I'm not sure what's triggering this as the code looks fine to me. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
function dateReduce() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1yl599Ff7d1aaSTKpHAeHW5wswiDOzNegrKxS1Z1SquY');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("worksheet");
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 6, 1374);
  var values = range.getValues(); // getValues() results in a javascript array as opposed to a google script array
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var endDate;
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    endDate = new Date(values[i][5]);
    if (yyyy > endDate.getFullYear()) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    };
    else if (yyyy === endDate.getFullYear()) {
      if ( mm > (endDate.getMonth()+1)) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
        };
    };
    else if ((mm === endDate.getMonth()+1) && (yyyy == endDate.getFullYear())) {
        if (dd > endDate.getDate()) {
          sheet.deleteRow(i);
        };
      };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the semicolons after all of the ending curly braces ("}"). You don't need to put semicolons after curly braces unless there is an assignment operation involved.

```
function dateReduce() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1yl599Ff7d1aaSTKpHAeHW5wswiDOzNegrKxS1Z1SquY');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("worksheet");
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 6, 1374);
  var values = range.getValues(); // getValues() results in a javascript array as opposed to a google script array
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var endDate;
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    endDate = new Date(values[i][5]);
    if (yyyy > endDate.getFullYear()) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    } else if (yyyy === endDate.getFullYear()) {
      if (mm > (endDate.getMonth() + 1)) {
        sheet.deleteRow(i);
      }
    } else if ((mm === endDate.getMonth() + 1) && (yyyy == endDate.getFullYear())) {
      if (dd > endDate.getDate()) {
        sheet.deleteRow(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's up and running now!